# Sever Side convert SVG to PNG or JPG image with Python on Google Application Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, svg

How to convert SVG to PNG or JPG image with Python on Google Application Engine?
Any idea?
Google Application Engine has PIL support. However, PIL doesn't support SVG.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! :) Please note that SO is for _high quality_ questions and answers; we like to help people who have obviously put some effort into asking their question before we put effort into answering their question. (We like a challenge.) I suggest reading http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for more details on what we like to see in our questions. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Server-side SVG to PNG (or some other image format) in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932408/server-side-svg-to-png-or-some-other-image-format-in-python)

Comment: It sounds like a duplicate but the GAE twist makes the answers from that QA not applicable. Installing Cairo on your server is a great idea if you control the server, but you can't do that on GAE.

Comment: @Matt, not a duplicate. The problem with GAE is that it is not possible to install/run binary libraries. Only pure Python2.5 can be used, and the implementation even has some further restrictions

Comment: BTW, App Engine does *not* have PIL support. The dev server requires PIL to emulate the images API, but you can't directly use PIL in either the production or dev environments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you manage to find (or write) a pure Python library to do this, it is likely to be prohibitive to run it on GAE due to the amount of computation required and the request time restrictions.

I would consider hosting the image conversion service elsewhere and have the GAE fetch the PNGs from there

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question, it basically says they're wrong to do it this way, but I see no reason why this isn't a legitimate question. This seems more like a comment than an answer to me.

Comment: @Shaun, how is it less of an answer than the jhocking's answer? At least this offers a useful alternative solution.

Answer (score 2):

When working with Google App Engine you will need a pure Python library because you can't install anything that's compiled (eg. Cairo). While there are pure Python libraries for creating SVG files (eg. [pySVG](http://codeboje.de/pysvg/)) I don't think there are any for rasterizing SVG images.