# Convert SVG to PNG in Python

Tags: python, svg, rendering, cairo

How do I convert an `svg` to `png`, in Python? I am storing the `svg` in an instance of `StringIO`. Should I use the pyCairo library? How do I write that code?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932408/server-side-svg-to-png-or-some-other-image-format-in-python

Comment: That thread left the problem unsolved. The accepted answer came from the asker who was sharing his failed code attempt. The other answer suggested ImageMagick but a commenter said ImageMagick does "a horrible job of interpreting SVG." I don't want my pngs to look horrible so I'm re-asking the question.

Comment: Try http://cairographics.org/cookbook/librsvgpython/

Comment: The examples in that link are specific to Win32. I'm running linux.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://guillaume.segu.in/blog/code/43/svg-to-png/) blog post, it looks like it might be what you need.

Comment: Simple SVGs: https://github.com/aslpavel/svgrasterize.py

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The answer is "[**pyrsvg**](http://cairographics.org/cookbook/pyrsvg/)" - a Python binding for [librsvg](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/LibRsvg).

There is an Ubuntu [python-rsvg package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python-rsvg) providing it. Searching Google for its name is poor because its source code seems to be contained inside the "gnome-python-desktop" Gnome project GIT repository.

I made a minimalist "hello world" that renders SVG to a cairo
surface and writes it to disk:

```
import cairo
import rsvg

img = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, 640,480)

ctx = cairo.Context(img)

## handle = rsvg.Handle(<svg filename>)
# or, for in memory SVG data:
handle= rsvg.Handle(None, str(<svg data>))

handle.render_cairo(ctx)

img.write_to_png("svg.png")
```

**Update**: as of 2014 the needed package for Fedora Linux distribution is: `gnome-python2-rsvg`. The above snippet listing still works as-is.

Comment: Great, works nicely. But is there a way to let `cairo` determine the HEIGHT and WIDTH of the picture on its own? I've looked into the `*.svg` file, to extract the HEIGHT and WIDTH from there, but it is both set to `100%`. Of course, I can look into the properties of the picture, but since this is only one step in image processing this is  not what I want.

Comment: If the "width" and "height" of your files are set to 100%, there is no magic Cairo or rsvg can do to guess the size: such SVG files were left size independent by the creator software(/person). The surrounding HTML code to import the SVG file would supply the physical size. However, the "Handle" object of rsvg do have a `.get_dimension_data()` method that worked for my example file (a well behaved SVG) - give it a try.

Comment: as of 2014, for ubuntu, you can use: apt-get install python-rsvg

Comment: Is there a quick command for adding a white background to the image if its current background is transparent?

Comment: @jsbueno I use Windows 8.1 and python 2.7.11 How can I install cairo and rsvg and make it work. I was struggling to make this work. BTW +1 for your detailed explanation.

Comment: @MarlonAbeykoon:  I think it is better you ask this as a separate question on another Stack Exchange forum - (I actually have no idea). Likely http://superuser.com  is your best choice. Just put a link to this question on your question there to give some more context to whoever knows how to answer this.

Comment: I used bit old version of wand to do it. Since latest version had some issues

Comment: The pyrsvg link is dead.

Answer (score 148):

Here is what I did using [cairosvg](http://cairosvg.org/):

```
from cairosvg import svg2png

svg_code = """
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
        <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"/>
        <line x1="12" y1="8" x2="12" y2="12"/>
        <line x1="12" y1="16" x2="12" y2="16"/>
    </svg>
"""

svg2png(bytestring=svg_code,write_to='output.png')
```

And it works like a charm!

See more: [cairosvg document](http://cairosvg.org/documentation/)

Comment: Hi. Do you know how can i do the same but without writing to a file? I need to push png content to the browser from a webserver, so that way the user can download the image. Saving the png file is not a valid option in our project, that's why I need it that way. Thanks

Comment: I've been doing this myself. It basically depends on what tools or frameworks u have at hand when handling your web requests, but no matter what it is, the basic idea is that `svg2png` takes in a `stream` object in the `write_to` parameter, and this can either be your HTTP Response object (which in most frameworks is a file-like object) or some other stream, which you then serve to the browser using the `Content-Disposition` header. see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012437/uses-of-content-disposition-in-an-http-response-header

Comment: For those who experiences the issues with that code, as I was:

1). `bytestring` accepts bytes, so convert string first with `bytestring=bytes(svg,'UTF-8')`

2). file mode should be binary, so `open('output.png','wb')`

Comment: The equivalent of @SerjZaharchenko's answer for Python 2.x is `bytestring=svg.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: If you want to set the width and height with `cairosvg`, the SVG must have a [`viewbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox). You can add one using [`scour`](https://github.com/scour-project/scour#usage).

Comment: cairosvg supports only Python 3.4+. They have dropped Python 2 support

Comment: Note that for python 2.7 you need to `pip install cairosvg==1.0.22` , otherwise you'll have installation issues.

Comment: There wasn't a `svg2png` for me, I had to use `cairosvg.surface.PNGSurface.convert(svg_str, write_to='output.png')`.

Comment: @estemendoza if you pass `write_to=None` it returns a bytestring.

Comment: @estemendoza Yes; here's how to do that: `PIL.Image.open(io.BytesIO(cairosvg.svg2png(url=filename, write_to=None)))`

Comment: If you have problems getting `CairoSVG` running on windows, see this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77712749/1725562

Answer (score 50):

Install Inkscape and call it as command line:

```sh
${INKSCAPE_PATH} -z -f ${source_svg} -w ${width} -j -e ${dest_png}
```

You can also snap specific rectangular area only using parameter `-j`, e.g. co-ordinate  "0:125:451:217"

```sh
${INKSCAPE_PATH} -z -f ${source_svg} -w ${width} -j -a ${coordinates} -e ${dest_png}
```

If you want to show only one object in the SVG file, you can specify the parameter `-i` with the object id that you have setup in the SVG. It hides everything else.

```sh
${INKSCAPE_PATH} -z -f ${source_svg} -w ${width} -i ${object} -j -a ${coordinates} -e ${dest_png}
```

Comment: +1 because this is also extremely handy for shell scripting.  See http://inkscape.org/doc/inkscape-man.html for full docs on Inkscape's command line.

Comment: Thanks, this was the easiest way I found to do this. On Windows, to make it so that you don't have to type in the full path to Inkscape every time, you can [add it to your Path in Environmental Variables](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm).

Comment: This is not an answer. It's a workaround. OP asked for a Python solution.

Answer (score 36):

I'm using [Wand-py](http://docs.wand-py.org/) (an implementation of the Wand wrapper around ImageMagick) to import some pretty advanced SVGs and so far have seen great results!  This is all the code it takes:

```
    with wand.image.Image( blob=svg_file.read(), format="svg" ) as image:
        png_image = image.make_blob("png")
```

I just discovered this today, and felt like it was worth sharing for anyone else who might straggle across this answer as it's been a while since most of these questions were answered.

*NOTE:* Technically in testing I discovered you don't even actually have to pass in the format parameter for ImageMagick, so  `with wand.image.Image( blob=svg_file.read() ) as image:` was all that was really needed.

EDIT: From an attempted edit by qris, here's some helpful code that lets you use ImageMagick with an SVG that has a transparent background:

```
from wand.api import library
import wand.color
import wand.image

with wand.image.Image() as image:
    with wand.color.Color('transparent') as background_color:
        library.MagickSetBackgroundColor(image.wand, 
                                         background_color.resource) 
    image.read(blob=svg_file.read(), format="svg")
    png_image = image.make_blob("png32")

with open(output_filename, "wb") as out:
    out.write(png_image)
```

Comment: Wand worked a **lot** better than Cairo for my PNGs.

Comment: Thanks @qris - added your transparent background SVG rendering code to my answer as well.

Comment: this looks nice, but where do you put the svg's filename??

Comment: I get the error     `image.read(blob=svg_file.read(), format="svg")
NameError: name 'svg_file' is not defined`

Comment: `svg_file` is assumed to be a "file" object in this example, setting `svg_file` would look something like: `svg_file = File.open(file_name, "r")`

Comment: Thanks, the `cairo` and `rsvg` 'accepted' method didn't work for my PDF. `pip install wand` and your snippet did the trick ;)

Comment: If you have an svg `str` then you first need to encode into binary like this: `svg_blob = svg_str.encode('utf-8')`. Now you can use the method above by replacing `blob=svg_file.read()` with `blob=svg_blob`.

Comment: This still didn't export correctly with fonts... I know that's not helpful... so specifically, I have an svg that utilizes the font-family property and loads all of the fonts from external stylesheets generated by font squirrel . com ...

Comment: FYI, i had trouble directly running the above code. First thing is that i had to install `potrace` from bioconda. Second, i actually end up using this `svg_to_png` function from https://www.programcreek.com/python/?code=yaqwsx%2FPcbDraw%2FPcbDraw-master%2Fpcbdraw%2Fpcbdraw.py# -- i hope it will be helpful for someone else too

Comment: With Wand 0.6.6 in MacOs, png_image was always None, make it works by adding background in constructor too: `image.read(blob=svg_file.read(), background=background_color), format="svg")`

Comment: FYI, this solution requires both Imagemagick and Inkscape to be installed.

Answer (score 30):

I did not find any of the answers satisfactory. All the mentioned libraries have some problem or the other like Cairo dropping support for python 3.6 (they dropped Python 2 support some 3 years ago!). Also, installing the mentioned libraries on the Mac was a pain.

Finally, I found the best solution was **svglib** + **reportlab**. Both installed without a hitch using pip and first call to convert from svg to png worked beautifully! Very happy with the solution.

Just 2 commands do the trick:

```
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
from reportlab.graphics import renderPM
drawing = svg2rlg("my.svg")
renderPM.drawToFile(drawing, "my.png", fmt="PNG")
```

Are there any limitations with these I should be aware of?

Comment: Yes, marker-end is not supported, and won't be, https://github.com/deeplook/svglib/issues/177

Comment: Great solution for those that work on Windows, absolutely no dependencies required at SO level. Thanks!!

Comment: In case you need to continue some operations with PIL `pil_img = renderPM.drawToPILP(drawing)`

Comment: Looks great, but svglib doesn't install properly via pip on Termux (the above answers don't seem to work on Termux, either, though).

Comment: In case you stumble over background transparency or scaling issues but don't want any external dependencies, check out [my workaround below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74165093/1506569)

Comment: I tried your code but it says: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'renderScale'

Comment: I tried this solution and get the following on windows :  

```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rlPyCairo'```

Answer (score 13):

Try this: http://cairosvg.org/

The site says:

> CairoSVG is written in pure python and only depends on Pycairo. It is
>   known to work on Python 2.6 and 2.7.

**Update** [November 25, 2016](https://github.com/Kozea/CairoSVG/blob/master/NEWS.rst#version-20-released-on-2016-11-24):

> 2.0.0 is a new major version, its changelog includes:
>
> - Drop Python 2 support

Comment: There is two problem with this, unfortunately. First, it doesn't handle the `<clipPath><rect ... /></clipPath>`. Second, it doesn't take the -d (DPI) option.

Comment: @Ray , please send bug reports / feature requests on [the CairoSVG tracker](https://github.com/Kozea/CairoSVG/issues)!

Comment: @Simon, Can you do it please? I'm too busy and I will be in the next 1-2 month.

Comment: @Ray, actually the -d / --dpi option has been there for a while now, and I’m told that support for <clippath> was added a few weeks back in the git version.

Comment: I had some problems with SVGs that use opacity. In my case Wand-py showed to be a better solution.

Answer (score 9):

Another solution I've just found here [How to render a scaled SVG to a QImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551690/how-to-render-a-scaled-svg-to-a-qimage#8551810)

```
from PySide.QtSvg import *
from PySide.QtGui import *


def convertSvgToPng(svgFilepath,pngFilepath,width):
    r=QSvgRenderer(svgFilepath)
    height=r.defaultSize().height()*width/r.defaultSize().width()
    i=QImage(width,height,QImage.Format_ARGB32)
    p=QPainter(i)
    r.render(p)
    i.save(pngFilepath)
    p.end()
```

PySide is easily installed from a binary package in Windows (and I use it for other things so is easy for me).

However, I noticed a few problems when converting country flags from Wikimedia, so perhaps not the most robust svg parser/renderer.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a another solution without using rsvg(which is currently not available for windows).Only install cairosvg using `pip install CairoSVG`

### svg2png.py

```
from cairosvg import svg2png
svg_code = open("input.svg", 'rt').read()
svg2png(bytestring=svg_code,write_to='output.png')
```

Comment: Another simpler way:
`cairosvg.svg2png(url="/path/to/input.svg", write_to="/tmp/output.png")`. As shared in Cairosvg's official documentation: https://cairosvg.org/documentation/

Answer (score 6):

A little extension on the answer of jsbueno:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cairo
import rsvg
from xml.dom import minidom


def convert_svg_to_png(svg_file, output_file):
    # Get the svg files content
    with open(svg_file) as f:
        svg_data = f.read()

    # Get the width / height inside of the SVG
    doc = minidom.parse(svg_file)
    width = int([path.getAttribute('width') for path
                 in doc.getElementsByTagName('svg')][0])
    height = int([path.getAttribute('height') for path
                  in doc.getElementsByTagName('svg')][0])
    doc.unlink()

    # create the png
    img = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, width, height)
    ctx = cairo.Context(img)
    handler = rsvg.Handle(None, str(svg_data))
    handler.render_cairo(ctx)
    img.write_to_png(output_file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from argparse import ArgumentParser

    parser = ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument("-f", "--file", dest="svg_file",
                        help="SVG input file", metavar="FILE")
    parser.add_argument("-o", "--output", dest="output", default="svg.png",
                        help="PNG output file", metavar="FILE")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    convert_svg_to_png(args.svg_file, args.output)
```

Comment: I used the svg width and height extraction.   I'm not sure about the svg standard but in some of my svg files the width or height were followed by a non numeric string such as 'mm' or 'px' (ex: '250mm'). The int('250mm') throws an exception and I had to make some additional tweaks.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach where Inkscape is called by Python.

Note that it suppresses certain crufty output that Inkscape writes to the console (specifically, stderr and stdout) during normal error-free operation. The output is captured in two string variables, `out` and `err`.

```
import subprocess               # May want to use subprocess32 instead

cmd_list = [ '/full/path/to/inkscape', '-z', 
             '--export-png', '/path/to/output.png',
             '--export-width', 100,
             '--export-height', 100,
             '/path/to/input.svg' ]

# Invoke the command.  Divert output that normally goes to stdout or stderr.
p = subprocess.Popen( cmd_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE )

# Below, < out > and < err > are strings or < None >, derived from stdout and stderr.
out, err = p.communicate()      # Waits for process to terminate

# Maybe do something with stdout output that is in < out >
# Maybe do something with stderr output that is in < err >

if p.returncode:
    raise Exception( 'Inkscape error: ' + (err or '?')  )
```

For example, when running a particular job on my Mac OS system, `out` ended up being:

```
Background RRGGBBAA: ffffff00
Area 0:0:339:339 exported to 100 x 100 pixels (72.4584 dpi)
Bitmap saved as: /path/to/output.png
```

(The input svg file had a size of 339 by 339 pixels.)

Comment: It's not end-to-end Python if you rely on Inkscape.

Comment: @Joel: First line has been modified to overcome your objection.  But of course, even a "pure" Python solution relies on elements outside the core language, and is ultimately run with machine language, so perhaps there is no such thing as end-to-end anything!

Answer (score 3):

## SVG scaling and PNG rendering

Using [pycairo](https://www.cairographics.org/pycairo/) and [librsvg](http://librsvg.sourceforge.net/download/) I was able to achieve SVG scaling and rendering to a bitmap. Assuming your SVG is not exactly 256x256 pixels, the desired output, you can read in the SVG to a Cairo context using rsvg and then scale it and write to a PNG.

### main.py

```
import cairo
import rsvg

width = 256
height = 256

svg = rsvg.Handle('cool.svg')
unscaled_width = svg.props.width
unscaled_height = svg.props.height

svg_surface = cairo.SVGSurface(None, width, height)
svg_context = cairo.Context(svg_surface)
svg_context.save()
svg_context.scale(width/unscaled_width, height/unscaled_height)
svg.render_cairo(svg_context)
svg_context.restore()

svg_surface.write_to_png('cool.png')
```

### RSVG C binding

From the Cario website with some minor modification. Also a good example of how to call a C-library from Python

```
from ctypes import CDLL, POINTER, Structure, byref, util
from ctypes import c_bool, c_byte, c_void_p, c_int, c_double, c_uint32, c_char_p


class _PycairoContext(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("PyObject_HEAD", c_byte * object.__basicsize__),
                ("ctx", c_void_p),
                ("base", c_void_p)]


class _RsvgProps(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("width", c_int), ("height", c_int),
                ("em", c_double), ("ex", c_double)]


class _GError(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("domain", c_uint32), ("code", c_int), ("message", c_char_p)]


def _load_rsvg(rsvg_lib_path=None, gobject_lib_path=None):
    if rsvg_lib_path is None:
        rsvg_lib_path = util.find_library('rsvg-2')
    if gobject_lib_path is None:
        gobject_lib_path = util.find_library('gobject-2.0')
    l = CDLL(rsvg_lib_path)
    g = CDLL(gobject_lib_path)
    g.g_type_init()

    l.rsvg_handle_new_from_file.argtypes = [c_char_p, POINTER(POINTER(_GError))]
    l.rsvg_handle_new_from_file.restype = c_void_p
    l.rsvg_handle_render_cairo.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_void_p]
    l.rsvg_handle_render_cairo.restype = c_bool
    l.rsvg_handle_get_dimensions.argtypes = [c_void_p, POINTER(_RsvgProps)]

    return l


_librsvg = _load_rsvg()


class Handle(object):
    def __init__(self, path):
        lib = _librsvg
        err = POINTER(_GError)()
        self.handle = lib.rsvg_handle_new_from_file(path.encode(), byref(err))
        if self.handle is None:
            gerr = err.contents
            raise Exception(gerr.message)
        self.props = _RsvgProps()
        lib.rsvg_handle_get_dimensions(self.handle, byref(self.props))

    def get_dimension_data(self):
        svgDim = self.RsvgDimensionData()
        _librsvg.rsvg_handle_get_dimensions(self.handle, byref(svgDim))
        return (svgDim.width, svgDim.height)

    def render_cairo(self, ctx):
        """Returns True is drawing succeeded."""
        z = _PycairoContext.from_address(id(ctx))
        return _librsvg.rsvg_handle_render_cairo(self.handle, z.ctx)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it proved very useful in a project of mine.

Although `Handle.get_dimension_data` didn't work for me. I had to replace it with a simple fetching of `self.props.width` and `self.props.height`. I first tried defining the `RsvgDimensionData` Structure as described on the cairo website, but without success.

Comment: I am trying to use this in a project of mine. How do I obtain the dll files required?

Answer (score 3):

Try this python script:

Don't forget to install cairosvg: `pip3 install cairosvg`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import cairosvg

for file in os.listdir('.'):
    if os.path.isfile(file) and file.endswith(".svg"):
        name = file.split('.svg')[0]
        cairosvg.svg2png(url=name+'.svg',write_to=name+'.png')
```

Comment: For an anaconda distribution use `conda install -c conda-forge cairosvg` rather than `pip3 install cairosvg` or the install will not work correctly. This works phenomenally for windows.

Answer (score 2):

Posting my code from [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74164750/1506569). It's a workaround to `svglib`+`reportlib` not supporting a transparent background and no scaling (see [@sarang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59505217/1506569) and [@ualter-jr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63113246/1506569) as well as these Github issues on [scaling not working](https://github.com/deeplook/svglib/issues/207) and [this one on transparency](https://github.com/deeplook/svglib/issues/171))

This uses `pyMuPDF` to render an intermediate pdf from `reportlab` to PNG.

The **big advantage** is that it *doesn't* need any external libraries as `pymupdf` comes with precompiled wheels for Windows, Linux and MacOS.

The whole thing is as easy as

```shell
pip install pymupdf svglib
```

and then executing the following lines

```python
import fitz
from svglib import svglib
from reportlab.graphics import renderPDF

# Convert svg to pdf in memory with svglib+reportlab
# directly rendering to png does not support transparency nor scaling
drawing = svglib.svg2rlg(path="input.svg")
pdf = renderPDF.drawToString(drawing)

# Open pdf with fitz (pyMuPdf) to convert to PNG
doc = fitz.Document(stream=pdf)
pix = doc.load_page(0).get_pixmap(alpha=True, dpi=300)
pix.save("output.png")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using Gtk.Image and Gdk.Pixbuf

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('Gdk', '3.0')

from gi.repository import Gdk, Gtk
from PIL import Image

image = Gtk.Image()
image.set_from_file("path/to/image.svg")
pb = image.get_pixbuf()
pb.savev("path/to/convented/image.jpeg","jpeg",[],[])
im = Image.open("path/to/convented/image.jpeg")
pix = im.load()
print(pix[1,1])
```

Comment: I am sure it would help the community if you explained to us why and how you code would solve the OP's problem

Comment: This works with SVG files that are not correctly rendered by Cairo, Inkspace but are correctly rendered by Gimp and Image Viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I did not want to be dependent of anything else but Python (Cairo, Ink.., etc.)
My requirements were to be as simple as possible, at most, a simple `pip install "savior"` would suffice, that's why any of those above didn't suit for me.

I came through this (going further than Stackoverflow on the research).
https://www.tutorialexample.com/best-practice-to-python-convert-svg-to-png-with-svglib-python-tutorial/

Looks good, so far. So I share it in case anyone in the same situation.

Comment: can you please include the relevant part of that article to your answer ?

Comment: looking at it, it seems to be identical to [Sarang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59505217/786559)

Answer (score 0):

All the answer's here are great, but I figure I'll mention that I have made a simple library that loads SVG's files as pillow Image instances which can then be exported. It uses inkscape like in blj's answer, but renders to stdout so that no temporary files are made. There's some basic usage stuff in the README.

https://github.com/jlwoolf/pillow-svg

EDIT:
As suggested, here's a brief explanation, since the link could become invalid:

The library uses inkscape's command line interface to convert the image to a png of a specific size or dpi using the python subprocess library. By setting `--export-filename` to `-`, inkscape redirects the output to the stdout. The first two lines are discarded, and the remaining output is passed to `PIL.Image.open`, converting it to pillow image instance.

```py
import subprocess
from PIL import Image

options = ["inkscape", "--export-filename=-", "--export-type=png", "file.svg"]

pipe = subprocess.Popen(options, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

pipe.stdout.readline()
pipe.stdout.readline()

img = Image.open(pipe.stdout)
```

From there you can do whatever pillow image operations you need (like export as a jpg, resize, crop, etc).

EDIT 2:
Just added support for [skia-python](https://pypi.org/project/skia-python/) (haven't fully tested it, but seems to work so far). This way you can convert an svg to png with only a single pip install (no need to use inkscape).

Here is an explanation of how the library uses skia-python:

First, the svg file is loaded into a `skia.SVGDOM`. From there you can grab the SVGDOM's dimensions, using `containerSize`. Then a `skia.Surface` of the desired image output size is made. The canvas is scaled to fit the svg to the surface, and then the svg is rendered. From there, an image snapshot can be made, which can then be fed to `PIL.Image.open`.

```py
import skia
from PIL import Image

skia_stream = skia.Stream.MakeFromFile("file.svg")
skia_svg = skia.SVGDOM.MakeFromStream(skia_stream)

svg_width, svg_height = skia_svg.containerSize()
surface_width, surface_height = 512, 512

surface = skia.Surface(surface_width, surface_height)
with surface as canvas:
    canvas.scale(surface_width / svg_width, surface_height / svg_height)
    skia_svg.render(canvas)

with io.BytesIO(surface.makeImageSnapshot().encodeToData()) as f:
            img = Image.open(f)
            img.load()
```

Edit 3:
I have fleshed out the library much much more. There is a command line utility now for easy svg conversion, along with more documentation explaining usage. Hope it helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31998847)