# How to render a scaled SVG to a QImage?

Tags: image, qt, svg

There is a `QSvgRenderer` class in `QtSvg` module which can render image onto `QPaintDevice`. This one can be `QImage`. In that case we will create:

```
Image svgBufferImage(renderer.defaultSize(), QImage::Format_ARGB32);
```

But how to render to a `QImage` of different size than default from the SVG renderer? Since the SVG format image can be scaled without quality loss, is it possible to generate static images, like PNG, from SVG files using `QSvgRenderer`?

Does anyone have a better idea? Basically I need to create images like PNG from SVG files in different sizes.

Answer (score 53):

Just give your `QImage` the desired size. The SVG renderer will scale to fit the whole image.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QSvgRenderer>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QImage>

// In your .pro file:
// QT += svg 

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // A QApplication instance is necessary if fonts are used in the SVG
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // Load your SVG
    QSvgRenderer renderer(QString("./svg-logo-h.svg"));

    // Prepare a QImage with desired characteritisc
    QImage image(500, 200, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
    image.fill(0xaaA08080);  // partly transparent red-ish background

    // Get QPainter that paints to the image
    QPainter painter(&image);
    renderer.render(&painter);

    // Save, image format based on file extension
    image.save("./svg-logo-h.png");
}
```

This will create an 500x200 PNG image from the passed in SVG file.

Example output with an SVG image from the [SVG logos](http://www.w3.org/2009/08/svg-logos.html) page:

[image]

Comment: See this for simpler solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079011/qpixmap-and-svg/36936216#answer-36936216

Comment: @Yash: simpler, but the question here specifically asks for scaling. (The answer above is a bit more complexe than necessary even for that, but demos other things you might need/want.)

Comment: @Mat yup. But SVG is free from any size so using pixmap method with provided QSize, It can be scaled whatever is required. You can create QIMage from pixmap.

Comment: This does not allow scale up. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52738410/returned-pixmap-from-svg-icon-does-not-scale-up

Comment: @V.K.: this does scale up/down with the SVG it was tested with. If you have an example where the above code doesn't scale an SVG, please share. Your other question is has quite a lot more going on with it.

Comment: That works fine (scaled to 1024x768, generated png is that big with the globe filling it).

Comment: @Mat Sorry, my mistake. I did something else wrong and need to find what. I confirm your solution works.

Comment: @Mat Actually this seems to lead me to the answer to my question... This is something I have not tried yet. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Here is complete answer:

```
QImage QPixmap::toImage()
```

If the pixmap has 1-bit depth, the returned image will also be 1 bit deep. Images with more bits will be returned in a format closely represents the underlying system. Usually this will be QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied for pixmaps with an alpha and QImage::Format_RGB32 or QImage::Format_RGB16 for pixmaps without alpha.

```
QImage img = QIcon("filepath.svg").pixmap(QSize(requiredsize)).toImage()
```

Also copy from above answer

```
// Save, image format based on file extension
image.save("./svg-logo-h.png");
```

Comment: `pixmap()` can potentially return a different size than `requiredsize` making this solution somewhat unpractical.

Answer (score 0):

If you have simple svg, like icon or small image, for replacing color for example, it's better to use [NanoSVG lib](https://github.com/memononen/nanosvg)

It has Qt wrapper, coded by me [Qt Svg Render](https://github.com/andr1312e/Qt-Svg-Stupid-Render).

It's very small, only 2 headers and one cpp.

Usage:

```
QString svgPath="your svg Path";
  QString pngPath="path for png";
  QSize imageSize(your image Path size);
  const QSize resultSize(size that you want to get);
  QImage image(sizeW, sizeH, Format);//End of param
  
  QFile svgFile(svgPath);
  if (svgFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
  {
      int svgFileSize=svgFile.size();
      QByteArray ba;
      ba.resize(svgFileSize + 1);
      svgFile.read(ba.data(), svgFileSize);
      ba.back() = {};
      if (auto const nsi(nsvgParse(ba.data(), "px", 96)); nsi)
      {
          image.fill(Qt::transparent);
          QPainter p(&image);
          p.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);

          drawSVGImage(&p, nsi, resultSize.width(), resultSize.height());

          nsvgDelete(nsi);
          image.save(pngPath);// if you want to save image
      }
  }
```