# QPixmap and SVG

Tags: qt, svg, qpixmap

How would you suggest to handle svg with QPixmap?

The construct `QPixmap(":/myfile.svg");` then call of `scaled()` does not work. The QPixmap gets pixelised.

Thx.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use [SVGRenderer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsvgrenderer.html) to render it onto a `QImage`. From there you can convert to a `QPixmap` with `QPixmap::convertFromImage`.

Comment: Thx, I did like suggested here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551690/qt-how-to-render-scaled-svg-to-qimage

Comment: It is possible to create QPainter over QPixmap and render SVG directly to the QPixmap.

Answer (score 40):

Now there is much simpler way without needing of SVG module

```
QIcon("filepath.svg").pixmap(QSize())
```

So simple and works fine. Atleast in my case it worked.

Comment: At least with respect to the limited use case of icons, **this should now be the accepted answer.** Note that the `QIcon::addFile()` method *also* implicitly accepts SVG files now, permitting each icon mode and state to be associated with its own SVG file.

Comment: This does not scale the SVG up, if it was smaller than this size, it stays the same.

Comment: This is great. But how do you achieve the same thing by creating a scalable icon from an bytearray containing SVG?

Answer (score 6):

Something like that:

```
QSvgRenderer renderer(svg_file_name);
QPixmap pm(width, height);
pm.fill(fill_color);
QPainter painter(&pm);
renderer.render(&painter, pm.rect());
```

Answer (score 1):

On Qt5.12 i managed to display SVG icons without pixellisation in a QLabel:

```cpp
QPixmap logoPixmap(":my-logo.svg"); // set your logo here
auto logoLabel = new QLabel(this);
logoLabel->setPixmap(logoPixmap);
logoLabel->setScaledContents(true);
logoLabel->setFixedSize(176, 61); // set your size here
```