# How to open svg file in QT (QGraphicsView)

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qtgui, qtsvg

How to open svg file like png file.
For example it works for png file:

```
scene=new QGraphicsScene(QRect(10, 10, 680, 520));  
view=new QGraphicsView(this);
image=new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap("example.png"));

scene ->addItem(image);   
view ->setScene(scene);   
view ->setGeometry(QRect(270, 35, 700, 540));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please elaborate? *How* doesn't it work for SVG files?

Comment: When i try to do it with svg file (example2.svg instead example.png) it shows me a white scene, not my example2.svg image. With example.png it works.

Comment: Duplicate question. I have just searched "QPixmap SVG" and find this in the first hint.

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079011/qpixmap-and-svg

Comment: Have you read about http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicssvgitem.html?

Comment: Yes. I wanted to try this but had other problem with qtsvg module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, you could use QGraphicsSvgItem as per [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicssvgitem.html#details):

> [QGraphicsSvgItem::QGraphicsSvgItem(const QString & fileName, QGraphicsItem * parent = 0)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicssvgitem.html#QGraphicsSvgItem-2)
>
> Constructs a new item with the given parent and loads the contents of the SVG file with the specified fileName.

So, you would basically write something as follows:

```
 QGraphicsSvgItem *item = new QGraphicsSvgItem("example.svg");
```

You can also follow th example in the documentation if you wish to use it with the `QSvgRenderer`.

```
QSvgRenderer *renderer = new QSvgRenderer(QStringLiteral("example.svg"));
QGraphicsSvgItem *item = new QGraphicsSvgItem();

item->setSharedRenderer(renderer);
item->setElementId(QStringLiteral("example"));
```

Here you can even find a more sophisticated example of doing this:

[SVG Viewer Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtsvg-svgviewer-example.html)

Comment: This is weird. I do as you wrote, but i got: "Cannot read file 'example.svg', because:  (line 2)". When file doesnt exist it shows: "Cannot read file 'example.svg', because:  No such file or directory"

Comment: @user3191398: can you open up the example.svg with an svn viewer, like inkscape or karbon, just to see if the svg is valid itself?

Comment: I can open. It is valid

Comment: Perhaps the svg viewer corrects a recoverable error. Please upload the svg to somewhere, and provide a link to us. Try another svg files as well, just in case.

Comment: @user3191398: as noted, the html should be changed at the top to xml to make it work. Perhaps, there is an explicit way of making it work, but this should get you going, at least.

Comment: I changed html to xml and it doesnt work. When i delete <xml> and <body> it works. Thanks a lot.