# PySide: How to set an SVG icon in QTreeWidget's item and change the size of the icon?

Tags: qt, python-2.7, svg, pyside, nuke

I have a UI that is using SVG icons in Nuke 8. While setting icons with the SVG files works fine, I cannot seem to find a way to change the size of the icons to a larger size in Qt. I have tried setting the icon's size and then load the SVG file, setting the icon on a widget and then place the widget in the QTreeWidgetItem, and setting the style sheet of the widget to use the SVG. I know I can scale up the SVG file before loading the file, but I prefer handling that inside of Qt.

Here's some example code of what I'm doing (This works, but the icon does not scale.):

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class TestTreeItem(QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, parent, value, status):
        super(TestTreeItem, self).__init__(parent)

        # Column 0
        self.setText(value)

        # Column 1
        # Using Qt Resources. All of the maps are to svg files.
        status_map = {0: ":/images/good",
        1: ":/images/warning",
        2: ":/images/error"}

        self.setSizeHint(1, QtCore.QSize(64, 64))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon(status_map[status])
        self.setIcon(1, icon)
```

## Code that doesn't work:

### Set the icon size and then load the icon

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class TestTreeItem(QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, parent, value, status):
        super(TestTreeItem, self).__init__(parent)

        # Column 0
        self.setText(value)

        # Column 1
        # Using Qt Resources. All of the maps are to svg files.
        status_map = {0: ":/images/good",
        1: ":/images/warning",
        2: ":/images/error"}

        self.setSizeHint(1, QtCore.QSize(64, 64))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon(QtGui.QSize(64, 64))
        icon.addFile(status_map[status])
        self.setIcon(1, icon)
```

### Create a pixmap and scale it

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class TestTreeItem(QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, parent, value, status):
        super(TestTreeItem, self).__init__(parent)

        # Column 0
        self.setText(value)

        # Column 1
        # Using Qt Resources. All of the maps are to svg files.
        status_map = {0: ":/images/good",
        1: ":/images/warning",
        2: ":/images/error"}

        self.setSizeHint(1, QtCore.QSize(64, 64))
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(status_map[status])
        pixmap.scaled(64, 64)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon(pixmap)
        self.setIcon(1, icon)
```

### Create an empty pixmap and then load the SVG

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class TestTreeItem(QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, parent, value, status):
        super(TestTreeItem, self).__init__(parent)

        # Column 0
        self.setText(value)

        # Column 1
        # Using Qt Resources. All of the maps are to svg files.
        status_map = {0: ":/images/good",
        1: ":/images/warning",
        2: ":/images/error"}

        self.setSizeHint(1, QtCore.QSize(64, 64))
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(QtGui.QSize(64, 64))
        pixmap.load(status_map[status])
        icon = QtGui.QIcon(pixmap)
        self.setIcon(1, icon)
```

### Create a widget and then set the style sheet to use the SVG

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class TestTreeItem(QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, parent, value, status):
        super(TestTreeItem, self).__init__(parent)

        # Column 0
        self.setText(value)

        # Column 1
        # Using Qt Resources. All of the maps are to svg files.
        widget = QtGui.QWidget(parent)
        status_map = {0: ":/images/good",
        1: ":/images/warning",
        2: ":/images/error"}

        self.setSizeHint(1, QtCore.QSize(64, 64))
        widget.setStyleSheet("image: url({});".format(status_map[status]))
        parent.setItemWidget(self, 1, widget)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I found a solution that works.

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore, QtSvg

class TestTreeItem(QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, parent, value, status):
        super(TestTreeItem, self).__init__(parent)

        # Column 0
        self.setText(value)

        # Column 1
        # Using Qt Resources. All of the maps are to svg files.
        status_map = {0: ":/images/good",
        1: ":/images/warning",
        2: ":/images/error"}

        svg_renderer = QtSvg.QSvgRenderer(status_map[status])
        image = QtGui.QImage(64, 64, QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32)
        # Set the ARGB to 0 to prevent rendering artifacts
        image.fill(0x00000000)
        svg_renderer.render(QtGui.QPainter(image))
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon(pixmap)
        self.setIcon(1, icon)

        self.setSizeHint(1, QtCore.QSize(64, 64))
```

This is based off of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8551810/3108288