# SVG QIcon cannot return scaled-up pixmap to be used in QToolButton

Tags: qt

I am using SVG images in my icons for `QToolButton`s. But I need to be able to change the size of the tool button and I need the icon to scale up or down. My SVG icons have native size of 24 (pixels). The trouble with `QIcon` is that they do not scale up above the native size. (see attempt0... in my code)

So I tried another approach, I overriden `resizeEvent` and used `QToolButton.setIconSize(event.size())` which worked perfect, it allowed scaling up and down without limits. (see attempt1... in my code)

But here comes my problem. I do need to make some pixel-wise color transform to my rendered icon. Therefore I need to get `QImage` which I can obtain from `QPixmap`. **But the problem is that I cannot get a SVG image rendered to a pixmap bigger than the SVG native size.** The pixmap itself is bigger but the image is still small, aligned to the center of the pixmap. I tried three different approaches, none of them worked. (see attempt2... to attempt4... in my code)

My code is here. For simpicity I left out the color pixel-wise transform which I am doing to the obtained pixmap/image.

toolbar.h

```
#pragma once

#include <QToolButton>

class ToolButton : public QToolButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ToolButton(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
protected:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event) override;
private:
    void attempt0_thisDoesNotScaleUp();
    void attempt1_thisScalesWellButIdoNotHavePixmap(int w, int h);
    void attempt2_thisDoesNotScaleUp(int w, int h);
    void attempt3_thisDoesNotScaleUp(int w, int h);
    void attempt4_thisDoesNotScaleUp(int w, int h);
    QString m_iconName;
};
```

toolbar.cpp

```
#include "toolbutton.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QResizeEvent>
#include <QtSvg/QSvgRenderer>

ToolButton::ToolButton(QWidget *parent) :
    QToolButton(parent)
{
    m_iconName = "icon.svg";
    // attempt0_thisDoesNotScaleUp(); // uncomment to try attempt 0
}

void ToolButton::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{

    int w = event->size().width();
    int h = event->size().height();

    //attempt1_thisScalesWellButIdoNotHavePixmap(name, w, h); // uncomment to try attempt 1
    //attempt2_thisDoesNotScaleUp(name, w, h); // uncomment to try attempt 2
    //attempt3_thisDoesNotScaleUp(name, w, h); // uncomment to try attempt 3
    //attempt4_thisDoesNotScaleUp(name, w, h); // uncomment to try attempt 4

    QToolButton::resizeEvent(event);
}

void ToolButton::attempt0_thisDoesNotScaleUp()
{
    setIcon(QIcon(m_iconName));
}

void ToolButton::attempt1_thisScalesWellButIdoNotHavePixmap(int w, int h)
{
    setIcon(QIcon(m_iconName));
    setIconSize(QSize(w, h));
}

void ToolButton::attempt2_thisDoesNotScaleUp(int w, int h)
{
    QIcon source(m_iconName);
    QPixmap pixmap = source.pixmap(w, h);
    QIcon icon;
    icon.addPixmap(pixmap);
    setIcon(icon);
}

void ToolButton::attempt3_thisDoesNotScaleUp(int w, int h)
{
    QSvgRenderer renderer(m_iconName);
    QPixmap pm(w, h);
    QPainter painter(&pm);
    renderer.render(&painter, pm.rect());
    QIcon icon;
    icon.addPixmap(pm);
    setIcon(icon);
}

void ToolButton::attempt4_thisDoesNotScaleUp(int w, int h)
{
    QIcon source(m_iconName);
    QPixmap pm(w, h);
    QPainter painter(&pm);
    source.paint(&painter, pm.rect());
    QIcon icon;
    icon.addPixmap(pm);
    setIcon(icon);
}
```

main.cpp (to show toolbutton as a main window to be able to test resizing)

```
#include "toolbutton.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    ToolButton w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

For testing I am using SVG icons from www.iconmonstr.com which have native size of 24x24 pixels. Of course I need to be able scale them above this size.

I guess I am missing something obvious... because `QToolButton::setIconSize(someBiggerSize);` is able to scale SVG icon up.

Comment: Try looking through the Qt code to see what the setIconSize does (it's a `QAbstractButton` function). I had a cursory look, but got lost in the web interface here: https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.11/src/widgets/widgets/qabstractbutton.cpp#L1278. Perhaps having code navigation tools on a locally downloaded copy will also help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the most stupid mistake I have made public here on SO: if I put `setIconSize(QSize(w, h));` at the end of each `attempt...` etc. methods, they all will work fine.

Despite the fact that the mistake was stupid, I will leave the answer here as a reference about how many ways we can use to render SVG.

UPDATE: there is yet another method for rendering SVG directly to `QImage` mentioned here [How to render a scaled SVG to a QImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551690/how-to-render-a-scaled-svg-to-a-qimage) This one actually seems best suited for my purpose. No need for intermediary pixmap.

Comment: Mate, we all make mistakes. No need to beat yourself up about it. I'm sure the internet will do it at some point :-) Not today.