# Text along the curves absence after convertion from svg to png using python+cairo+rsvg

Tags: python, svg, cairo, inkscape, rsvg

I'm trying to convert SVG to PNG using Python, Cairo and librsvg. Everything is okay, except of the text typed along the curve. This text is blank on the result PNG image, although the normal horizontal text is OK.

[image: Creating svg image with inkscape]
[image: As a result png with bare curves]
[Here is the source of my example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589358/convert-svg-to-png-in-python)

Comment: Can you Pastie up your SVG file? I wonder if it has something to do with Inkscape supporting proposed extensions for 1.1 that were abandoned - `flowPara` maybe?

Comment: Maybe relevant: http://en.dev.inkscape.org/faq/#what-about-flowed-text

Comment: @halfer: no flowed-text is much different, this is about textPath support, not arbitrary region textwrapping.

Comment: Here is the [original SVG](http://192.168.1.7/share/curve-text.svg)

Comment: OK, fair enough (your SVG file is on a LAN IP address, btw - use pastie.org `:-)`).

Comment: Thank you halter! [real original SVG](http://pastie.org/3717462)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

textPath doesn't seem to be supported in librsvg, see e.g http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=577844