# PIL and vectorbased graphics

Tags: python, svg, python-imaging-library, vector-graphics, eps

I run into several problems when I try to open EPS- or SVG-Images with PIL.

Opening EPS

```py
from PIL import Image
test = Image.open('test.eps')
```

ends in:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1965, in open
    return factory(fp, filename)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 91, in __init__
    self._open()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py", line 206, in _open
    raise IOError, "bad EPS header"
  IOError: bad EPS header
```

Also opening SVG ends in `IOError: cannot identify image file`.

The problem is I have to support both formats in my application. Converting to other formats is no alternative. I'm on Windows 7, Python 2.7.2 and PIL 1.1.7.

I uploaded both images: [EPS](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/24705455/Altana_Logo_CMYK.eps) and [SVG](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/24705455/Altana_Logo_2007.svg).

Comment: PIL doesn't support SVG format. EPS format is not fully supported. See http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/index.htm.

Comment: So, is there any alternative to PIL in the python world?

Answer (score 15):

As of today, that is July 2017, reading and converting SVG files can be easily accomplished by importing **cairosvg** that provides the **svg2png** function.

Furthermore the **svglib** development is on again, thus by importing svglib and **reportlab**, the conversion from svg to png should be easy as well. a matter of 2 calls.

Comment: To add on this answer, it is a matter of just three commands (plus imports): after `from io import BytesIO`, `import cairosvg`, `from PIL import Image`, just run `out = BytesIO()`, `cairosvg.svg2png(url='path/to/svg', write_to=out)`, `image = Image.open(out)`

Comment: After a lot of search, I found svglib and reportlab to be the best options! Installed using pip, called and it just worked - lovely! Thanks!

Comment: It might be worth noting that python has no good way of support SVG 2.0. Both cairosvg and svglib only support up to SVG 1.1.

Answer (score 8):

There are alternatives to PIL, but alternatives to PIL are not what you want - There is no
library I know of that would transparently open a vector based drawing and treat it just as any other image, short of opening a web browser and grabbing its render.

For dealing with SVG, there is a recipe using Cairo - which also can handle a lot of other formats, if a bit more difficult to deal with than the PIL API - I think Cairo can also handle EPS - so, you can probably develop your app with pycairo - or pycairo + PIL in the worst case.

The recipe for rendering SVG's is in the answer to: [Convert SVG to PNG in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589358/convert-svg-to-png-in-python/6599172#6599172)

(note that you don't have to "convert the file to PNG" - the recipe shows how you render to a cairo surface, which can be displayed, saved to a file, and so on)

Answer (score 1):

Yet, Pillow supports EMF (Enhanced Windows Metafile) which is still vector graphics. I stumbled on this thread as I was searching for convenient mean to convert SVG to EMF anyway.
Your best bet is to use Inkscape to create EMF from SVG:

`inkscape --file image.svg --export-emf image.emf`

Answer (score 0):

`PIL` doesn't support `svg`, but you could try [`svglib`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/svglib/)

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/svglib/
- https://github.com/deeplook/svglib

Comment: Luckily, svglib development seems to be now back again. Version 0.8.1 currently in the PyPI supports Python 2.7 and 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

While I believe the top answer is better, one is able to leverage Inkscape to render SVG to PNG files.

```
render_image_command = "inkscape --export-background-opacity=0 --export-width={} --export-type=png --export-filename {} {}"

render_image_command = render_image_command.format(
    image_width_in_pixels,
    path_to_png_image_to_write,
    path_to_svg_image_to_read
)
```