# Insert an svg image in matplotlib figure

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, svg, figure, insets

This is a follow-up to my previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65387500/insert-a-png-image-in-a-matplotlib-figure).

I'm trying to add an SVG image in matplotlib figure as inset.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox


ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(
    [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3],
    'go-',
    label='line 1',
    linewidth=2
 )
arr_img = plt.imread("stinkbug.svg")
im = OffsetImage(arr_img)
ab = AnnotationBbox(im, (1, 0), xycoords='axes fraction')
ax.add_artist(ab)
plt.show()
```

The code works when the input image is in png format. But I am not able to add the same image saved in svg extension([image](https://github.com/DeepaMahm/misc/blob/master/stinkbug.svg)).

I get the following error

```
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file
```

EDIT:
I tried to read the svg file via svglib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg

ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(
    [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3],
    'go-',
    label='line 1',
    linewidth=2
 )
# arr_img = plt.imread("stinkbug.svg")
arr_img = svg2rlg("stinkbug.svg")
im = OffsetImage(arr_img)
ab = AnnotationBbox(im, (1, 0), xycoords='axes fraction')
ax.add_artist(ab)
plt.show()
```

Error:

```
"float".format(self._A.dtype))
TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float
```

Could someone please have a look?

Comment: This seems to answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130670/pil-and-vectorbased-graphics

Comment: @foglerit Could you please check my edit?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45262575/189418), you can use cairosvg to first convert your SVG to PNG, and then add to your figure.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox
from cairosvg import svg2png

ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(
    [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3],
    'go-',
    label='line 1',
    linewidth=2
 )
# arr_img = plt.imread("stinkbug.svg")
svg2png(url="stinkbug.svg",  write_to="stinkbug.png")

arr_img = plt.imread("stinkbug.png")
im = OffsetImage(arr_img)
ab = AnnotationBbox(im, (1, 0), xycoords='axes fraction')
ax.add_artist(ab)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ran the code posted above. Unfortunately, I get the following error `raise OSError("dlopen() failed to load a library: %s" % ' / '.join(names))
OSError: dlopen() failed to load a library: cairo / cairo-2 / cairo-gobject-2 / cairo.so.2`

Comment: I suggest you try to install `cairosvg` with conda: `conda install cairosvg -c conda-forge`

Comment: Is there no way to import the svg object as such and save everything as a vector image? One of the main advantages of matplotlib is that the output is vector image when saved as svg or pdf.