# read an svg file to insert in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, svg, figure, insets

I am trying to read an image from an SVG file and insert in matplotlib figure.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylustrator as pyl
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg

ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(
    [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3],
    'go-',
    label='line 1',
    linewidth=2
 )
# arr_img = plt.imread("stinkbug.svg")
# arr_img = svg2rlg("stinkbug.svg")
arr_img = pyl.load("stinkbug.svg")
im = OffsetImage(arr_img)
ab = AnnotationBbox(im, (1, 0), xycoords='axes fraction')
ax.add_artist(ab)
plt.show()
```

I tried to use `pylustrator`[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161559/plot-svg-within-matplotlib-figure-embedded-in-wxpython) for reading the svg image. The code works when the input image is in png format. But I am not able to add the same image saved in svg extension([image](https://github.com/DeepaMahm/misc/blob/master/stinkbug.svg)).

I couldn't successfully insert due to the following error,

```
    "float".format(self._A.dtype))
TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float
```

Suggestions on how to fix this will be really helpful.

Comment: @Randrian Could you please have a look?

Comment: How does this differ from the second half of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66540026/insert-an-svg-image-in-matplotlib-figure) i.e. why aren't they duplicates?