# PIL to create SVG images

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I was wondering is there a way to create an SVG image with PIL library?

I need to create a black square of about 500x500px and add some simple text to it, I know this is an easy task for PIL. But I couldn't find any way to save it as SVG to my computer

Comment: Hi, take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130670/pil-and-vectorbased-graphics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PIL/Pillow is a **raster** image processor, a.k.a. **bitmap** image processor and incapable of generating **vector** output such as SVG.

However, if you really just need a 500x500 black rectangle with some simple text, you can write that yourself without any library dependencies:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Create SVG string - more examples here https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_intro.asp
svg = """<?xml version="1.0"?><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="500">
  <rect width="500" height="500" style="fill:rgb(0,0,0)" />
  <text x="20" y="200" fill="yellow">Some simple text.</text>
</svg>
"""

# Write to a text file
with open('image.svg', 'w') as f:
    f.write(svg)
```

The file contents obviously look like the string `svg` in the code, and you can convert it to a PNG for viewing with **ImageMagick** like this:

```
magick image.svg result.png
```

You could equally use your web browser to visualise it by clicking on `File`->`Open File` and selecting `image.svg`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [svgwrite](https://pypi.org/project/svgwrite/), and save yourself the effort of hand-crafting XML. It's no longer in active development, but the sample script seems to work.