# Convert SVG path to image

Tags: python, svg

I have a big SVG path which is retrieved from the HTML source of a webpage. We can use a smaller example though, like this:

```
<svg height="210" width="400">
  <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
</svg>
```

I want to convert it to an image (probably bitmap) that will eventually be displayed in wxPython, in a wxFrame.

Are there any libraries or standard procedures to doing something like this?

Comment: There are lots of options, for example, http://cairosvg.org/

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589358/convert-svg-to-png-in-python