# Python script calling shell script with Image Magick

Tags: python, bash, imagemagick, subprocess, imagemagick-convert

I have a bash script that has calls to the "convert" command in ImageMagick. This script works fine when I execute it in the terminal manually. Clearly I have the path to the 'convert' command added to my system path. When I try to execute it using a another script(written in python) , I run into an error the 'convert' is not found. Here is a simple example to reproduce the issue. I am on OSX Maverick.

---

### Shell script: convert_svg_to_png.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in *.svg; do

        convert "$filename" "`basename $filename .svg`.png"

done
```

---

### Python script: runme.py

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call('./convert_svg_to_png.sh')
```

---

Error:
./convert_svg_to_png.sh: line 5: convert: command not found

---

Any idea why this error?

Edit: When the bash script is modified to include the whole path to the convert function. This new error pops up:

dyld: Library not loaded: /ImageMagick-6.8.9/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16.2.dylib
  Referenced from: %FullPath%convert
  Reason: image not found

The shell being called by python is /bin/bash. Same as in my terminal.

Comment: In the shell you are using to run python, what happens when you type `which convert`

Comment: also what is your `$PATH` set to in that shell

Comment: and you are sure if you run the shell script directly from that same shell, it works?

Comment: which python gives this: /Users/myusername/Desktop/libraries/ImageMagick-6.8.9/bin/convert . Also $PATH includes this folder: /Users/myusername/Desktop/libraries/ImageMagick-6.8.9/bin/ . It works when I run manually, I've also got the desired outputs.

Comment: hmmm, very weird, according to the `subprocess` docs, the default behavior is to inherit the current process environment...

Answer (score 1):

A few things...

1. Ensure that the `convert` utility is reachable by your `$PATH` environment variable.

   ```
   export PATH="${PATH}:/Users/myusername/Desktop/libraries/ImageMagick-6.8.9/bin"
   ```
2. If ImageMagick's ecosystem lives in a special place, set environment `$MAGICK_HOME`; such that, the runtime libraries can find everything.

   ```
   export MAGICK_HOME=/Users/myusername/Desktop/libraries/ImageMagick-6.8.9
   ```
3. When invoking `subprocess.call`, set the keyword argument `shell=True`.

   ```
   import subprocess

   subprocess.call('./convert_svg_to_png.sh', shell=True)
   ```

Comment: I tried the above things, but still the same error. I think that the first two steps are necessary for even using the `convert` utility from the terminal.

Comment: I don't know why but in OSX(10.11) works only without shell=True.

Answer (score 1):

Ok then first try to verify if the command 'convert' is install on your machine. Which I think you do.

```
which convert
```

python program

```
import subprocess

command = 'bash convert_svg_to_png.sh'.split()

try:
    result = subprocess.check_call(command)
    print('successful')
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    print('An error occurs')
```

if you are using python3 then you can use `shutil.which` which will find the system path of `convert` or return None

#### python 3

```
import shutil
import subprocess

result = shutil.which('convert')

if result:
    command = 'bash convert_svg_to_png.sh'.split()
    try:
        result = subprocess.check_call(command)
        print('successful')
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        print('An error occurs')
```

You could also use `wand` package which is a wrapper around Imagemagick http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.1/guide/write.html#convert-images-to-jpeg or you could go to that post to see if there is a better approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/19718153/2581266