# Simple way of adding a saving tool to mpld3 plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, save, mpld3

[mpld3](http://mpld3.github.io/index.html) is great to convert very quickly a matplotlib figure to an interactive HTML file, just one line of code is required:

```
  mpld3.save_html(fig,filename)
```

While [bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) requires rewriting the figure code with bokeh commands. 
However, mpld3 does not provide the very useful and basic tool "save" in addition to zoom and pan.

Has someone found a simple way of adding this tool?

Comment: >the very useful and basic tool "save" in addition to zoom and pan. 
What do you mean by that? Look at [some examples](http://mpld3.github.io/examples/custom_plugin.html) of mpld3, they have zoom and pan (Down to the left is this).

Comment: yes they have pan and zoom but no save option. I am talking about a save icon, like in bokeh or plotly

Comment: I do not think I have that mpl3d. It occurs to me that you can use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)  to get the svg, and/or use something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6599172/5420829) to convert it to PNG.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like just a simple tool so I can share an html file with non-coders, they can play with the interactive plot and then save it. But it seems like the answer is no.