# Convert a SVG to PNG using python?

Tags: python-3.x, svg, png

I have to convert a .svg file to a .png file.

I **don't** need a command line.

I'm using python 3.9.2 64-bit

I'm using windows10

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589358/convert-svg-to-png-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert SVG to PNG in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589358/convert-svg-to-png-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the library [`pyvips`](https://pypi.org/project/pyvips/)

And use it like this:

```py
import pyvips

image = pyvips.Image.new_from_file("img.svg", dpi=300)
image.write_to_file("img.png")
```