# How to create Captcha image from raw data

Tags: python, web-scraping, captcha

I got the captcha raw data, need to convert it into an image(png or jpg). The browser can create the image from raw data, the same operation I want to do using Python.
please suggest

```
{
  "captcha": "<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" width=\"150\" height=\"50\" viewBox=\"0,0,150,50\"><path fill=\"#222\" d=\"M122.06 40.14L121.98 40.05L120.04 40.40L119.89 40.25Q119.49 40.30 118.52 40.36L118.51 40.35L118.45 40.29Q117.54 40.41 117.04 40.41L116.99 40.35L117.07 40.44Q115.40 40.40 114.37 39.56L114.44 39.63L114.30 39.49Q115.19 38.48 116.82 36.35L116.73 36.25L116.77 36.30Q118.02 37.85 120.23 37.62L120.24 37.62L120.28 37.67Q121.19 37.55 121.83 36.90L121.75 36.82L121.95 37.02Q122.55 36.32 122.43 35.45L122.42 35.43L122.38 35.39Q122.25 30.77 122.33 26.20L122.28 26.15L122.39 26.26Q122.41 21.64 122.94 17.03L122.87 16.96L122.85 16.94Q124.96 16.91 127.09 15.89L126.97 15.77L126.95 15.75Q125.03 22.43 125.03 29.67L125.13 29.76L125.09 29.73Q125.06 33.24 125.52 36.74L125.58 36.80L125.63 36.85Q125.56 37.05 125.56 37.39L125.64 37.47L125.67 37.50Q125.61 38.01 125.38 38.54L125.51 38.67L125.51 38.67Q124.90 39.89 122.08 40.15ZM127.07 43.05L126.89 42.87L127.41 43.05L127.51 42.73L127.86 42.70L127.86 42.70Q128.08 42.35 128.16 42.24L128.26 42.33L128.26 42.34Q128.41 41.12 128.14 40.13L128.07 40.05L128.14 40.13Q126.81 34.34 127.08 27.99L127.17 28.08L127.06 27.97Q127.29 21.83 129.08 15.93L129.15 16.01L129.12 15.98Q128.28 16.66 127.02 17.38L126.90 17.26L126.99 17.35Q127.16 16.57 127.58 15.05L127.57 15.04L127.65 15.11Q125.03 16.34 122.36 16.64L122.42 16.70L122.37 16.65Q122.08 21.12 122.00 26.07L121.97 26.04L122.07 26.13Q121.88 31.92 121.95 35.34L121.98 35.37L121.98 35.37Q122.08 37.19 120.33 37.34L120.32 37.33L120.36 37.37Q118.51 37.35 116.84 35.71L116.88 35.75L116.94 35.81Q114.88 38.32 113.93 39.88L113.94 39.89L113.83 39.79Q114.54 40.50 115.57 40.73L115.52 40.67L115.56 40.71Q115.47 40.85 115.20 41.08L115.14 41.02L115.30 41.18Q116.66 42.05 118.64 42.31L118.74 42.41L118.68 42.35Q119.09 42.42 122.38 42.72L122.42 42.76L122.38 42.72Q125.65 43.00 127.02 43.00Z\"/><path d=\"M13 13 C67 38,88 26,143 37\" stroke=\"#222\" fill=\"none\"/><path d=\"M8 16 C72 49,72 35,144 28\" stroke=\"#555\" fill=\"none\"/><path fill=\"#444\" d=\"M15.10 15.85L15.13 15.88L15.05 15.80Q17.05 20.77 17.62 25.95L17.50 25.83L17.62 25.95Q21.36 21.84 27.26 17.01L27.20 16.95L27.14 16.89Q30.33 16.57 32.95 15.77L32.98 15.80L26.48 21.49L26.52 21.52Q23.02 24.38 20.17 27.24L20.17 27.24L20.09 27.16Q28.07 36.32 33.14 41.04L33.25 41.16L33.10 41.01Q30.07 40.15 27.74 39.99L27.85 40.10L27.76 40.01Q21.96 34.59 17.65 28.76L17.70 28.81L17.76 28.87Q17.81 35.43 15.95 40.76L15.86 40.67L15.90 40.71Q15.71 40.79 15.21 40.98L15.20 40.96L15.10 41.06L15.15 41.11Q14.98 41.16 12.43 42.08L12.54 42.19L12.47 42.11Q15.34 35.47 14.99 28.01L15.01 28.02L14.94 27.95Q14.78 20.78 11.24 14.27L11.23 14.26L11.78 14.54L12.22 14.87L12.22 14.84L12.28 14.89Q12.96 15.23 15.17 15.92ZM15.31 15.49L15.48 15.66L15.34 15.52Q13.12 15.02 10.50 13.50L10.41 13.41L10.47 13.47Q14.83 20.84 14.83 29.79L14.74 29.69L14.72 29.68Q14.79 36.74 11.82 42.80L11.89 42.87L13.81 41.90L13.81 41.89Q13.48 42.97 12.79 44.26L12.75 44.22L12.75 44.23Q14.99 43.42 16.93 43.00L17.03 43.10L16.92 42.76L17.10 42.94Q17.22 42.76 17.79 42.61L17.81 42.63L17.90 42.72Q19.48 36.71 19.59 31.92L19.55 31.87L19.67 31.99Q21.61 34.36 23.44 36.22L23.50 36.28L23.62 36.40Q24.76 37.47 27.77 40.44L27.70 40.37L27.71 40.37L27.79 40.46Q28.81 41.29 30.68 42.89L30.59 42.80L30.57 42.78Q34.49 43.54 37.96 45.26L37.94 45.24L37.97 45.27Q28.59 36.61 22.34 29.19L22.40 29.25L22.39 29.24Q26.86 25.02 35.61 16.42L35.52 16.32L35.66 16.46Q33.05 17.55 31.03 17.93L31.10 17.99L31.11 18.01Q32.18 16.87 34.51 14.85L34.50 14.85L34.54 14.88Q30.49 16.36 27.14 16.55L27.01 16.41L27.16 16.57Q24.19 18.73 19.31 23.41L19.27 23.37L19.36 23.46Q18.95 20.85 18.38 18.30L18.38 18.30L18.44 18.35Q17.26 18.20 16.27 17.86L16.20 17.79L16.13 17.71Q16.02 17.08 15.45 15.63Z\"/><path d=\"M19 48 C93 5,67 41,131 19\" stroke=\"#555\" fill=\"none\"/><path fill=\"#222\" d=\"M55.82 41.59L55.87 41.65L55.82 41.60Q53.74 41.23 51.57 41.07L51.52 41.03L51.52 41.03Q49.98 39.49 47.32 35.64L47.36 35.68L47.40 35.73Q45.23 38.85 42.83 41.29L42.85 41.30L40.74 41.66L40.73 41.65Q39.63 41.82 38.64 42.08L38.59 42.03L38.70 42.13Q42.80 37.94 45.80 33.82L45.86 33.88L45.88 33.90Q42.61 29.71 37.20 24.92L37.16 24.87L37.11 24.82Q39.32 25.55 42.02 25.97L42.04 25.99L42.10 26.04Q45.58 29.18 47.48 31.88L47.40 31.80L47.51 31.92Q49.49 28.71 52.23 26.20L52.32 26.29L52.32 26.30Q55.33 25.91 57.15 25.42L57.28 25.54L57.21 25.47Q52.69 29.14 49.00 33.71L49.01 33.72L48.91 33.62Q52.30 38.30 55.76 41.53ZM58.68 24.73L58.61 24.66L58.65 24.71Q55.75 25.53 52.21 25.88L52.19 25.86L52.29 25.96Q49.38 28.60 47.66 31.08L47.62 31.03L47.65 31.06Q46.71 29.97 45.07 27.99L45.06 27.97L44.84 27.95L44.85 27.96Q44.82 28.05 44.71 28.05L44.62 27.96L44.73 28.07Q43.90 27.17 42.27 25.72L42.28 25.73L42.15 25.61Q38.67 25.17 35.81 23.95L35.75 23.88L35.82 23.96Q41.35 28.76 45.39 33.90L45.44 33.96L45.39 33.90Q41.96 38.47 37.54 42.77L37.57 42.80L37.57 42.80Q37.85 42.73 41.35 41.89L41.42 41.96L41.33 41.88Q39.73 43.13 38.10 44.47L38.22 44.59L38.23 44.60Q41.32 43.58 44.48 43.39L44.48 43.39L44.48 43.39Q47.00 41.27 48.91 38.53L48.90 38.52L48.83 38.45Q50.25 40.21 51.47 41.39L51.44 41.36L51.44 41.36Q51.62 41.43 51.70 41.51L51.56 41.36L51.73 41.35L51.91 41.53Q53.01 42.48 54.35 43.55L54.38 43.58L54.40 43.60Q58.05 44.20 60.94 45.23L60.90 45.19L60.95 45.24Q54.77 40.77 51.07 35.59L51.00 35.52L50.97 35.48Q54.68 30.52 59.25 26.44L59.20 26.40L59.29 26.49Q58.27 26.76 57.28 26.99L57.29 26.99L55.33 27.52L55.34 27.52Q56.51 26.60 58.68 24.73Z\"/><path fill=\"#333\" d=\"M95.95 41.20L95.91 41.17L94.21 41.17L94.25 41.22Q90.78 41.14 89.83 39.01L89.88 39.06L89.83 39.01Q90.96 37.92 92.40 36.82L92.40 36.82L92.46 36.88Q93.13 39.15 95.99 38.99L95.86 38.87L95.86 38.87Q96.69 38.86 97.72 38.64L97.69 38.60L97.81 38.72Q98.70 38.17 98.62 37.21L98.53 37.12L98.57 37.16Q98.46 36.02 96.67 35.34L96.75 35.41L92.96 33.91L92.80 33.75Q90.54 32.48 90.20 28.94L90.24 28.98L90.12 28.86Q90.08 26.88 92.25 26.31L92.23 26.30L92.23 26.29Q93.24 26.12 96.20 26.12L96.18 26.09L96.11 26.02Q100.90 25.94 101.82 28.45L102.00 28.64L101.98 28.62Q101.31 29.13 100.59 29.58L100.61 29.60L99.10 30.46L99.20 30.55Q98.58 28.53 95.35 28.31L95.32 28.28L95.35 28.31Q94.73 28.30 93.70 28.72L93.73 28.74L93.75 28.76Q93.13 29.05 93.13 30.16L93.13 30.16L93.19 30.22Q93.49 31.24 95.31 31.93L95.45 32.07L95.30 31.91Q96.55 32.48 99.21 33.58L99.07 33.43L99.04 33.40Q100.96 34.34 101.15 36.89L101.20 36.94L101.09 36.83Q101.15 37.46 101.08 38.45L101.20 38.58L101.17 38.54Q101.10 39.39 100.53 40.04L100.58 40.08L100.57 40.08Q98.91 41.12 95.87 41.12ZM100.67 43.75L100.59 43.67L100.66 43.74Q101.62 43.82 102.99 43.52L102.86 43.40L102.89 43.42Q104.07 42.85 103.87 41.63L103.81 41.56L103.74 41.50Q103.71 40.97 103.41 39.37L103.44 39.41L103.43 39.39Q102.95 36.51 101.16 35.30L101.06 35.20L101.08 35.22Q100.66 33.92 99.41 33.20L99.33 33.13L99.27 33.07Q98.08 32.72 95.61 31.76L95.68 31.83L95.50 31.65Q95.79 31.33 96.05 31.22L95.91 31.07L95.98 31.15Q96.56 30.66 97.21 30.62L97.35 30.76L97.29 30.70Q97.99 30.56 98.75 30.83L98.85 30.93L98.88 31.04L99.01 31.05L99.25 31.10L99.16 31.05L99.13 31.02Q100.27 31.55 100.46 32.81L100.40 32.74L100.47 32.81Q101.73 31.98 103.63 30.31L103.62 30.29L103.53 30.21Q103.26 29.48 102.27 28.30L102.41 28.44L102.43 28.45Q101.26 25.73 96.16 25.62L96.04 25.49L96.06 25.51Q93.02 25.60 91.04 26.17L91.07 26.20L90.94 26.07Q89.53 26.64 89.76 28.73L89.77 28.74L89.88 28.85Q89.83 29.94 90.74 32.04L90.88 32.18L90.80 32.09Q91.37 33.24 92.40 33.96L92.32 33.88L92.40 33.97Q93.05 35.41 94.35 36.10L94.32 36.08L94.36 36.11Q95.23 36.30 96.19 36.68L96.28 36.78L98.14 37.50L98.20 37.55Q97.80 38.60 95.86 38.48L95.83 38.45L95.92 38.54Q95.45 38.57 94.23 38.26L94.31 38.34L94.12 38.00L94.04 38.15L94.12 38.23Q93.20 37.81 92.56 36.33L92.59 36.36L92.58 36.35Q90.45 37.91 89.35 39.06L89.31 39.02L89.37 39.08Q89.54 39.86 90.57 40.66L90.57 40.66L90.51 40.90L90.40 40.80Q92.00 43.08 96.22 43.46L96.09 43.33L96.23 43.47Q97.33 43.43 100.57 43.65Z\"/><path fill=\"#333\" d=\"M70.92 29.82L70.81 29.71L70.86 29.76Q66.70 29.60 66.13 32.65L66.14 32.65L66.07 32.58Q65.95 33.72 66.14 34.59L66.01 34.46L66.02 34.47Q66.10 35.32 66.56 36.72L66.52 36.69L66.53 36.70Q67.57 39.83 70.88 39.68L71.02 39.82L70.98 39.78Q72.97 39.83 74.30 38.26L74.26 38.22L74.29 38.26Q75.42 36.68 75.42 34.63L75.41 34.62L75.57 34.77Q75.73 34.21 75.58 33.15L75.40 32.97L75.51 33.08Q75.43 32.16 75.02 31.48L74.96 31.42L74.94 31.40Q73.49 29.91 70.90 29.80ZM75.65 48.18L75.66 48.19L75.62 48.15Q73.78 48.70 65.71 49.09L65.71 49.09L65.81 49.19Q64.12 49.25 62.49 48.42L62.42 48.35L62.54 48.47Q63.24 47.38 65.07 45.59L65.21 45.73L65.13 45.66Q67.46 46.61 69.55 46.42L69.59 46.46L69.65 46.52Q72.59 46.30 73.43 46.04L73.27 45.88L73.30 45.90Q75.55 45.22 75.55 43.43L75.61 43.49L75.57 43.45Q75.64 43.29 75.56 43.06L75.46 42.96L75.33 41.35L75.51 41.52Q75.31 40.57 75.31 39.77L75.45 39.90L75.32 39.78Q74.01 42.08 70.62 42.08L70.69 42.16L70.60 42.06Q66.69 42.03 65.05 39.83L65.16 39.94L65.18 39.95Q64.06 38.41 63.26 34.00L63.30 34.04L63.21 33.95Q62.90 32.42 62.90 31.01L62.81 30.92L62.82 30.93Q63.00 29.33 63.92 28.34L63.80 28.22L63.82 28.24Q65.51 26.85 70.15 26.85L70.21 26.90L71.88 27.01L71.81 26.95Q75.01 27.29 76.35 29.23L76.37 29.26L76.37 29.25Q76.53 28.39 76.95 26.75L76.93 26.73L77.05 26.85Q78.83 26.43 80.58 25.70L80.68 25.80L80.57 25.69Q77.84 31.72 77.84 38.95L77.90 39.01L78.00 39.10Q78.03 41.80 78.41 44.43L78.37 44.39L78.30 44.32Q78.46 44.97 78.38 45.65L78.44 45.71L78.52 45.79Q78.33 47.16 77.11 47.92L76.93 47.74L77.00 47.82Q76.44 48.01 75.60 48.13ZM78.76 51.25L78.60 51.09L78.63 51.12Q80.10 51.18 80.86 50.23L80.96 50.33L80.89 50.26Q81.28 49.35 81.17 48.63L81.06 48.52L81.07 48.53Q81.01 47.94 80.82 47.18L80.85 47.21L80.88 47.24Q79.62 41.98 79.96 36.73L79.91 36.68L79.97 36.74Q80.27 31.25 82.40 26.41L82.47 26.48L80.42 27.48L80.32 27.38Q80.49 26.71 80.72 26.14L80.77 26.19L81.32 25.10L81.38 25.17Q78.90 26.00 76.69 26.41L76.79 26.52L76.71 26.43Q76.38 27.28 76.23 28.31L76.36 28.45L76.19 28.28Q74.05 26.32 70.01 26.32L70.12 26.43L68.33 26.40L68.26 26.33Q65.14 26.44 63.46 27.84L63.36 27.74L63.54 27.92Q62.60 28.89 62.64 30.79L62.49 30.64L62.50 30.65Q62.63 33.22 63.66 37.48L63.67 37.50L63.59 37.41Q64.18 39.45 65.40 40.86L65.30 40.76L65.56 41.02L65.67 41.13L65.58 41.04Q66.92 43.56 69.50 44.09L69.41 44.00L69.40 43.99Q70.88 44.36 72.33 44.40L72.21 44.28L72.36 44.44Q74.12 44.47 75.18 44.09L75.11 44.02L75.11 44.02Q74.51 45.59 71.85 45.93L71.87 45.96L71.83 45.92Q70.70 46.01 70.02 46.01L70.15 46.15L69.71 46.09L69.67 46.05Q66.85 46.04 65.17 45.09L65.20 45.11L63.49 46.83L63.43 46.77Q62.57 47.59 61.73 48.54L61.74 48.55L61.84 48.64Q62.83 49.17 63.82 49.36L63.80 49.35L62.96 50.26L62.82 50.11Q65.62 51.28 71.26 51.28L71.14 51.17L71.49 51.29L71.45 51.24Q75.00 51.18 78.58 51.07ZM72.66 31.98L72.74 32.06L72.68 32.00Q74.07 32.02 74.99 32.44L74.99 32.45L74.89 32.34Q75.13 32.89 75.20 33.57L75.26 33.63L75.25 33.61Q75.25 33.88 75.21 34.79L75.24 34.82L75.13 34.72Q75.21 36.78 74.11 38.07L74.09 38.05L73.93 37.89Q72.79 39.34 70.88 39.30L70.84 39.26L70.90 39.31Q69.49 39.28 68.65 38.86L68.66 38.87L68.57 38.77Q68.29 37.74 68.25 36.71L68.20 36.66L68.31 36.76Q68.16 32.39 72.77 32.09Z\"/></svg>"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have received a JSON structure containing the `captcha` field, and its value is an [SVG document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics). Some of the ways to render that to a bitmap image are discussed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589358/convert-svg-to-png-in-python), and I would personally choose [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13320450/5936187). Here's a small code sample:

```py
import cairosvg
import io
import json

# fetch your JSON
json_string = web_fetch('https://example.com/captcha')

# parse it into a python object and extract the SVG document
svg = json.loads(json_string)['captcha']

# note: your SVG document declares its size to be 150x50 pixels,
# which may be too small for some users to see; consider varying the `scale` parameter

# write image to file
cairosvg.svg2png(bytestring=svg, write_to='captcha_output.png', scale=3)

# or to memory to use it later
buf = io.BytesIO()
cairosvg.svg2png(bytestring=svg, write_to=buf, scale=3)
```

For more info, check out the [`cairosvg` docs](https://cairosvg.org/documentation/).