# Convert SVG to PNG with custom font in Python

Tags: python, svg, png, cairo, wand

I have read and tried several threads, but I was unable to solve this problem.

I have a simple SVG file:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 289 144.94">
    <defs>
        <style type="text/css">
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cabin:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700');
        </style>
        <style type="text/css">
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cabin:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700');
        </style>
        <style type="text/css">.cls-11{font-size:53.58px;}
        </style>
    </defs>
    <text class="cls-11" textLength="110" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" transform="translate(160.98 45.54)">M2/1</text>
</svg>
```

But I'm unable to generate a PNG output for this SVG in Python. I have tried cairosvg, pyvips, wandpy, but all had some sort of issues.
Mainly the 2 problem:

- The imported font is not loaded/not recognized.
- The lenghtAdjust parameter seems to be ignored by most of them.

It would be also acceptable for me to generate another pixel-based format from this or use another programming language/library.

Comment: The same question has been asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589358/convert-svg-to-png-in-python @Kristof Rado you can follow this link and look for one of the good upvoted answers

Comment: Please check my response in the answer provided which has the same link as yours.
This does not solve my problem with fonts and additional svg attributes like 'lengthAdjust'

Answer (score -1):

```
from cairosvg import svg2png

from cairosvg import svg2png

svg_code = """
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
        <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"/>
        <line x1="12" y1="8" x2="12" y2="12"/>
        <line x1="12" y1="16" x2="12" y2="16"/>
    </svg>
"""

svg2png(bytestring=svg_code,write_to='output.png')
```

this example was given by a user called "JWL", does the below link answer your question?

[Convert SVG to PNG in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589358/convert-svg-to-png-in-python)

Comment: No it won't work on my example. The font is not loaded (default font is used) and the lenghtAdjust parameter is ignored (text is outside of viewBox if the text is longer).

Comment: This was downvoted because it does not address how to port a font into the svg to be outputted in the png.