# Convert SVG image to PNG image by python

Tags: python, svg

I have use svglib with this code :

```
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
from reportlab.graphics import renderPM

drawing = svg2rlg('''E:/img/1926_S1_style_1_0_0.svg''')
renderPM.drawToFile(drawing, 'image.jpg', fmt='jpg')
```

But what i receive [image: What i convert]
It's from the image of SVG like [image]
So what should i do to convert SVG to PNG in the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using [cairosvg](http://cairosvg.org/)

```py
from cairosvg import svg2png

svg_code = """
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
        <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"/>
        <line x1="12" y1="8" x2="12" y2="12"/>
        <line x1="12" y1="16" x2="12" y2="16"/>
    </svg>
"""

svg2png(bytestring=svg_code,write_to='output.png')
```

[answer by JWL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13320450/19313724)