# Converting SVG to PNG python

Tags: python, pycairo

I'm having problems converting an SVG to a PNG in python. I'm using Cairosvg and this is what my code looks like.

```
from cairosvg import svg2png

f = open(f"{filename}.svg")
svg2png(bytestring=f.read().encode("utf-8"),write_to=f"{filename}.png")
f.close()
```

However it always comes up with this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\PycharmProjects\QR Code Scanner\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import QrUtil
  File "d:\PycharmProjects\QR Code Scanner\QrUtil.py", line 11, in <module>
    from cairosvg import svg2png
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\QR Code Scanner\venv\lib\site-packages\cairosvg\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import surface  # noqa isort:skip
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\QR Code Scanner\venv\lib\site-packages\cairosvg\surface.py", line 9, in <module>
    import cairocffi as cairo
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\QR Code Scanner\venv\lib\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    cairo = dlopen(
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\QR Code Scanner\venv\lib\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 45, in dlopen
    raise OSError(error_message)  # pragma: no cover
OSError: no library called "cairo-2" was found
no library called "cairo" was found
no library called "libcairo-2" was found
cannot load library 'libcairo.so.2': error 0x7e
cannot load library 'libcairo.2.dylib': error 0x7e
cannot load library 'libcairo-2.dll': error 0x7e
```

Can anybody help, even if you can suggest a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `pyvips` ?

```
import pyvips

image = pyvips.Image.new_from_file("something.svg", dpi=300)
image.write_to_file("x.png")
```

If you want to learn more, check out the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62876618/11608114)

Comment: Also, as stated in the linked answer, pyvips depends on libvips, so you may need to install that too in order to get it to work.

Comment: Does not work on alpine images. Hard to install this libvips.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you probably don't have GTK installed. According to [a similar bug report on GitHub](https://github.com/mindee/doctr/issues/529), Cairo depends on GTK. Once I [installed GTK](https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows), I was able to use Cairo to convert an SVG to PNG using your code.

Alternatively, you can try [SVGLib](https://pypi.org/project/svglib/):

```
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
from reportlab.graphics import renderPM

drawing = svg2rlg("file.svg")
renderPM.drawToFile(drawing, "file.png", fmt="PNG")
```